# Chef Server opscode-reporting with wrong Postgresql credentials

Tags: linux, chef

I'm using Chef 12.5.0 and I recently discoverd that after an update the reporting isn't working anymore. So I executed:

```
opscode-reporting-ctl reconfigure
```

and got the following error:

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "opscode-pgsql"

So I looked into the cookbook opscode-reporting to check where the Cookbook get its credentials from. And it looks like it just gets everything from the node attributes. Here's my first problem:
My Node doesn't have any attributes that match the ones in the cookbook (like reporting). So in my understanding chef can't get any attributs because none are defined on the needed one are defined on this node.
Here's the strange part, the cookbook somehow finds a user to auth with (opscode-pgsql).
I tried to change passwords in the attributes files but that didn't helped and was also for the wrong user since the mentioned user doens't exist in the attributes file.

How can I bring back chef-reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason opscode-reporting-ctl sets a different postgres password than the running instance of chef server. I managed to fix this by copying the opscode-pgsql user password from `/etc/opscode/chef-server-running.json` and pasting it on `/etc/opscode-reporting/opscode-reporting-secrets.json`.

Comment: Awesomme! Just needed to put the password in the db_superuser_password key